# Rsync to Synology NAS with public key does not work as expected

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, synology, public-key, ssh-keygen

I know that this question is asked a lot, but none of the answers could help me so far. I am trying to copy files via rsync from an ubuntu server to a Synology nas without a password prompt.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-92-generic x86_64) and DSM version is DSM 7.1.1-42962 Update 6.

I already failed at the first step of creating a working public key and confirming that it works.

In my Ubuntu shell, I do the following:

```
sudo su
ssh-keygen [I just hit enter on passphrase]
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub [my-admin-user]@[my synology ip]
```

So far everything seems to work out. But when I try:

```
ssh [my-admin-user]@[my synology ip]
```

I still get a password prompt. What am I doing wrong? `[my-admin-user]` is not `root`, but another account which belongs to the admin group on my Synology device, but I don't know if that matters.

Running `ssh -v [my-admin-user]@[my synology ip]` gets me (last part, I think this is relevant):

```
debug1: Authenticating to [my synology ip]:[port] as [my-admin-user]
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:[some/key]
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host [my synology ip] is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[another/key]
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-               256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-ni               stp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[some/other/key]
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: do `ssh -v user@ip` and see why the key auth failed or if it was even attempted. The server (or client) might not have `PubkeyAuthentication` enabled for example. If you have multiple keys, you might need to specify which one to use, like with `ssh -i`

Comment: “I already failed at the first step of creating a public key and confirming that it works.” What does this mean? Were you able to copy the public key to the destination server?

Comment: By first step I meant configuring a working public key which seems to fail. I'll update to make it clearer.

Comment: It didn't like the `id_rsa` key your client sent. Try running `ssh-copy-id user@ip` without specifying `-i`, then `ssh user@ip` again?

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: The permissions were `777` for both. I changed that and redid the process, still no luck. I saw some old keys from previous attempts in my authorized_keys so I deletet the id_rsa files and the authorized key file. Redid the whole thing, changed permissions to `600`/`700``. In my Synology web interface I can see the file, containing one line looking like ` ssh-rsa [key]= `[ubuntu-user]@[name-of-ubuntu-machine]. Still, trying to ssh gets me a password prompt.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help so far. I managed to make it work after some more reading of some forums. I can now `ssh` into my server using a root user after setting the following permissions on the nas: `chmod 0711 ~ chmod 0711 ~/.ssh chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. No luck with rsync-user though, but it is a first step in the right direction.